# Assistance Identifying Unknown Grasshopper Line Operation

Tags: grasshopper, rhino3d

Can anybody help me identify the grasshopper line operation circled in red? I am stumped.... any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!
[Unknown Line operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5dAg.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I recommend asking in the Rhino forum: https://discourse.mcneel.com/

Answer (score 1):

that is called "point on curve"